# Считывание нажатия клавиши в консоли через msvcrt

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Нужно через **msvcrt** считать нажатие клавиши и допустим написать "Привет!" если это "Enter"
Помогите пожалуйста

Windows, Python 3.5

Comment: А можно узнать, почему именно через msvcrt?

Comment: @andreymal задание такое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте примерно так.

```
from msvcrt import getch
key = getch()
if key==b'\r':
    print("Привет!")
```

Comment: откуда взято значение клавиши "Enter" \r?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что `b'\r' != '\r'` в Питоне 3.